# How would I increase the hardcoded ring size in my fork?

Tags: monero-forks, ringsize

As the title says. I want to increase the ring size that is hardcoded into a file that I can't find. I checked most of the code in the src/ringct directory and can not find it.

Where is the hardcoded value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blockchain::check_tx_inputs, in src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp

The code is a bit complicated since it checks various cases for older conensus rules, which you probably don't need and that you can remove.

Comment: Is the line where it says "size_t ring_size = !tx.vin.empty() && tx.vin[0].type() == typeid(txin_to_key) ? boost::get<txin_to_key>(tx.vin[0]).key_offsets.size() : 0;" The one to change? Should I just remove everything after the "=" and enter my custom ring size?

Comment: Well, you need to read that code and understand what it does first.

Comment: I changed it to 2 to test it and I changed it in wallet2.cpp as well. But now, when I sent it with ring size of 2 the daemon rejects it due to the ring size being incorrect. Where else is it referenced?

Comment: I think that's it.  You migh have missed the min_ring_size in the function I mentioned above. The ring size used to be variable so it's not a simple equality check.

Comment: I've CTRL + F blockchain.cpp in the src/cryptonote_core/ directory and there is no reference of min_ring_size. Where is it?

Comment: min_mixin (1 less than ring size)

Comment: One last question, occasionally it spits out an error when transfering saying "histogram reports no unlocked rct outputs, not even ours"  What's causing this? I set ring size to 5 and min mixin to 4. I have unlocked balance when transfering yet it still happens every now and then.

Comment: It means that your wallet has at least one output of amount A (if ringct, the amount is 0 as a placeholder), but when the wallet asked the daemon "how many unlocked outputs of amount A are there on the chain", the daemon answered "none". Which is nonsensical, unless you're trying to spend an output that's not unlocked yet, but the wallet should have code preventing this.